# Which piece of data in the spec of a monitor do I need to look at if I want it to look COMFORTABLE for long-time use?

Tags: monitors

I feel some monitors look less tiring than others for long-time use. What information in the spec of the monitor is the most relervant to this? The spec includes resolution, refresh rate, color range, color accuracy, brightness, and many other numbers. Which ones are related to the confort of our eyes?

Comment: Panel type. I find IPS to be better than TN and VA.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, brightness and color temperature are what lead to eye strain after prolonged use. I use a program called f.lux https://justgetflux.com/ that adjusts the brightness and color temperature of my screen based on the time of day. There is also a "reduce eyestrain" setting you can use all the time.